# Can't get simplest yml reference tag sample working

Tags: gitlab-ci

Following [the gitlab reference for reference tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#reference-tags), this simplest example doesn't work.

**.gitlab-ci.yml:**

```
include:
  - local: shared.yml

this-doesnt-work:
  script:
    - !reference [.test, script]
```

**shared.yml:**

```
.test:
  script:
    - echo from shared
```

But gitlab doesn't seem to replace the reference, it tries to execute the literal ".test":
*Executing "step_script" stage of the job script

$ .test

/bin/bash: line 106: .test: command not found*

Comment: Does it work if you have the .test template in your .gitlab-ci.yml file?  Seems like the syntax is correct.  Wondering if the shared.yml file import didn't work.

Comment: I linted .test in line with this-doesnt-work with success on version 13.10.  Didn't go as far as creating a test repo.

Comment: Having .test template in another file is the whole purpose of reference tags, otherwise you use YAML anchors, right?  Which strikes me as strange; why not use the same method across files?  In any case, it is importing the file, it tells me the file isn't present if I misspell it, and it tells me it's already imported if I try to import it from another yml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine. Which gitlab version are you using? The `!reference` feature was introduced with gitlab [13.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/02/22/gitlab-13-9-released/). Maybe you are running an older version?

Comment: Sheesh, running 13.8.4